# How do I bind an enum to a ComboBox and hide a certain value in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, enums

I have an enum in the form of:

```
public enum BlueOrRed { None, Blue, Red}
```

Currently I am binding that to a ComboBox in Code because the binding is dependent on a selection in another ComboBox:

```
if (OtherComboBox.SelectedItem == Color.BlueOrRed)
{
    ThisComboBOx.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(BlueOrRed));
}
else ...
```

I need the option, that BlueOrRed could also be None in the code behind. But I don't want to display that option in the ComboBox.

I am aware of a similar [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997898/binding-wpf-combobox-to-enum-and-hiding-certain-values), but that answer unfortunately doesn't really aplly to my problem.

Comment: `ItemsSource = new BlueOrRed[] { BlueOrRed.Blue, BlueOrRed.Red };`

Comment: It could be an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3591923/11404117). But I have not tested it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GetValues` method will return *all* of these constants as an array. Instead create a custom list.

```
ThisComboBOx.ItemsSource = new List<BlueOrRed> {BlueOrRed.Blue, BlueOrRed.Red};
```

If you do not want to create the list yourself, you can also exclude the `None` constant using Linq.

```
ThisComboBOx.ItemsSource = ((BlueOrRed[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof(BlueOrRed))).Except(new[] { BlueOrRed.None });
```